# What is the proper way of creating an instance of an 'included' class in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, include, typeerror

To start with, I am working on an AngularJS 1 project with ES5, and I am looking to include some external library to use it for logging.

In order to use the external library, I chose to add the script tag in order to include it as a global variable (it was the the easiest way for me to include a library). I did that by adding the following code to the head section in the index.gsp file:

```
<script src="//blah/blah/my-library.js"></script>
```

Then, I added the statement below to a javascript file in my project (that is the file that needs to use the library):

```
var ClientLogging = new ClientLogging(params);
```

However, when execution reaches the line above, it throws the following exception:

```
TypeError: ClientLogging is not a constructor
```

Here is the external library class that I would like to use in code:

```
const util = require('./utilities/util');

class ClientLogging {

    constructor(params) {
        // some code here
        this.errorLogger = new ErrorLogger(params);
    } 

    logError(message, error, ) {
        this.errorLogger.logError(message, error);
    }
}

module.exports = ClientLogging;
```

So, what is the right way of getting an instance of the ClientLogging class in my code?

P.S. The external library is written in ES6, and my code is in ES5.

Comment: Don't use `var ClientLogging` for an instance of the class `ClientLogging`.

Comment: How exactly are you including that code, as-is with just a `<script>` tag? The `require` and `module.exports` stuff needs rewriting, like a bundler does it.

Comment: It could be an ordering issue - you need to make sure your library is loaded before your code executes.

Comment: @Bergi The only thing I am doing is to add the <script> tag to include that library. What do you mean by a "bundler"?

Comment: @DuncanThacker How to make sure that the library is loaded before code execution?

Comment: @AbabnehA Just make sure you script tag for the library is above the script tag for your main code in the HTML - script tags are loaded and executed in order in HTML

Comment: @AbabnehA Instead of getting a `TypeError: ClientLogging is not a constructor`, you should be getting `TypeError: require is not a function` in a normal browser environment.